# grep for a string which has a specific number in the end

Tags: grep

I want to grep for the string `THREAD: 2`. It has a **space** in between. Not able to figure out how.

I tried with `grep "THREAD:[ \2]"`, but its not working

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try `grep "THREAD: 2" <filename>`? You just want a literal '2', right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GNU grep you could try using the alias egrep or grep -e with 'THREAD: 2$'

You might have to use '^.*THREAD: 2$'

Answer (score 0):

`grep` reports back the entire line that has matched your pattern. If you wish to look at lines that contains `THREAD: 2` then the following should work -

```
grep "THREAD: 2" filename
```

However, if you wish to fetch lines that could contain `THREAD:` and any number then you can use a character class. So in that case the answer would be -

```
grep "THREAD: [0-9]" filename
```

You can add `+` after the character class which means one or more numbers so that you can match numbers like 1,2,3 or 11,12,13 etc.

If you only want to fetch `THREAD: 2` from your line then you will have to use an option of `grep` which is `-o`. It means show me only my pattern from the file not the entire line.

```
grep -o "THREAD: 2" filename
```

You can look up `man page` for `grep` and play around with all the options.